# Data Frame to matrix - many rows

Tags: r

I'm trying to convert data.frame to matrix. I calculated some statistics for iris dataset and want every statistics to be placed in seperate row. Code below shows all statistics (avg and median) in one single row and that's not a desired output. I want sth like this:

```
stat Sepal.Lenght  Sepal.Width  ....
avg     10.5          .....
med    ......         .....
```

Code below:

```
data_iris <- iris
avg <- data_iris %>%
  summarise_at(vars(Sepal.Length:Petal.Width),mean,na.rm=TRUE)

med <- data_iris %>%
  summarise_at(vars(Sepal.Length:Petal.Width),median,na.rm=TRUE)


column <- colnames(data_iris[1:4])
rown <- c("avg","median")

df <- data.frame(avg=avg,med=med)
m <- data.matrix(df)
```

And additional question: I'd like to calculate quantiles but error comes up:

```
qrtl <- data_iris %>%
  summarise_at(vars(Sepal.Length:Petal.Width),quantile,na.rm=TRUE)
```

error: Column `Sepal.Length` must be length 1 (a summary value), not 5

What's wrong?

Comment: Base R alternative for fun, which gives the `matrix` output - `sapply(data_iris[1:4], function(x) c(mean=mean(x),median=median(x)))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It can be  done if we do a reshape into 'long' with `pivot_longer`

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
iris %>% 
   summarise_if(is.numeric, list(avg = mean, med = median)) %>% 
   pivot_longer(everything(), names_to = c('.value', 'stat'), names_sep="_")
#    stat Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width
#1  avg     5.843333    3.057333        3.758    1.199333
#2  med     5.800000    3.000000        4.350    1.300000
```

---

If it needs to be converted to `matrix`, then change the 'stat' to rownames and then use `data.matrix`

```
library(tibble)
iris %>% 
   summarise_if(is.numeric, list(avg = mean, med = median)) %>% 
   pivot_longer(everything(), names_to = c('.value', 'stat'), names_sep="_") %>% 
   column_to_rownames('stat') %>%
   data.matrix
```

---

The `quantile` is working fine in the `dev` version of `dplyr` - 0.8.99.9000`

```
iris %>%        
    summarise_at(vars(Sepal.Length:Petal.Width),quantile, na.rm=TRUE)
#  Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width
#1          4.3         2.0         1.00         0.1
#2          5.1         2.8         1.60         0.3
#3          5.8         3.0         4.35         1.3
#4          6.4         3.3         5.10         1.8
#5          7.9         4.4         6.90         2.5
```

The OP's package version is `0.8.3`, so may be wrapping with `list` would work

```
iris %>%
   summarise_at(vars(Sepal.Length:Petal.Width),
         list(quantile = ~ list(quantile(., na.rm=TRUE)))) %>% 
   unnest(c(names(.)))
```

Comment: Thanks. For quantile I use the same (I even copied it form your post) code and this is what i got: `+   summarise_at(vars(Sepal.Length:Petal.Width),quantile, na.rm=TRUE)
ERROR: Column `Sepal.Length` must be length 1 (a summary value), not 5`

Comment: @Muska Can you show your `dplyr` `packageVersion('dplyr')`.  I think it must be related to the versioni

Comment: Yes, current version is 0.8.3

Comment: @Muska  I am using the dev version `‘0.8.99.9000’`, but in your case, it can be rectified if we wrap it in a `list`

Comment: @Muska Can you try `iris %>%        
    summarise_at(vars(Sepal.Length:Petal.Width),list(quantile = ~ list(quantile(., na.rm=TRUE)))) %>% unnest(c(names(.)))`

Answer (score 0):

We can use `map` with `transpose` and then bind rows from different statistics together.

```
library(purrr)

map(data_iris[1:4], ~list(mean = mean(.x), sd = sd(.x))) %>%
  transpose() %>%
  dplyr::bind_rows(.id = "statistics")

# A tibble: 2 x 5
#  statistics Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width
#  <chr>             <dbl>       <dbl>        <dbl>       <dbl>
#1 mean              5.84        3.06          3.76       1.20 
#2 sd                0.828       0.436         1.77       0.762
```

Or

```
map_df(data_iris[1:4], ~c(mean = mean(.x), sd = sd(.x)))
```